# Both If-else statement executing when checking Bundle arguments

Tags: android, if-statement, bundle

In my Android app I'm replacing a Fragment passing an int as argument:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment ();

FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
bundle.putInt("id", myId);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
ft.addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.placeholder, fragment).commit();
```

Inside MyFragment, I'm checking if this Bundle is null:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
    Bundle args = this.getArguments();

    if(args != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "args: "+args);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "no args: "+args);
    }

    return v;
}
```

My Logcat result:

> args: Bundle[{id=1}]
>
> no args: null

Why both if and else are executing?

Comment: That method must be executing twice.  Not sure why that is happening though.

Comment: they are not called at same time,onCreateView is being called multiple times

Comment: That's it! onCreateView is executing twice.

Answer (score 1):

> Why both if and else are executing?

they are probably two different transactions. One that you committed programmatically, the other is probably declared in the layout of hosting activity